# How to automatically close all collapsible elements inside of the accordion when closing the accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I found this topic here on stack overflow: [Closing parent accordion needs to close all children accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100545/closing-parent-accordion-needs-to-close-all-children-accordion) which contains more or less what I'm searching for.

I'm using bootstrap 4 and my problem is that I do not know how to adapt the code from the other topic to make it possible that accordion and also single collapsible items will be closed when closing main accordion card...

Can anybody help? Here is my example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fgh0qw9x/

What I tried until now is to adapt the code like this:

```
 closeChildrenAccordion : function (accordion) {
            if (jQuery(".show")) {
                jQuery(".show").unbind().click(function () {
                    jQuery(accordion).removeClass('show');
                    var parentPanelHeading = jQuery(this).closest('.card-header'); // Get parent
                    var siblings           = parentPanelHeading.siblings()[0]; // Get div that needs to be closed when closing parent div

                    if(jQuery(siblings).hasClass("in"))
                    {
                        jQuery(siblings).find('a').each(function (index, element) {
                            if(jQuery(element).hasClass('show'))
                                element.click();
                        });
                    }


                });


            }
        }
```

But I am quite honest, I don't really understand the code and hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a handler to the [`hide.bs.collapse`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#events) that fires just before collapsing an item and then `find` other collapsible elements that are currently open. This should work for elements at any depth:

```
$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).find('.collapse.show').removeClass('show');
})
```

We remove the class directy because if you tried to toggle the accordion using its api, it will trigger the `hide.bs.collapse` event again.

Comment: how can i specify that the function will only be called when closing the main accordion? i tried it with a separate class at beginning `$('.call-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function()...` that I pasted in the main accordion. But unfortunately this doesn't work. - Reason is that I have some collapsible inside the accordion that should not be closed when open another one inside. Only when closing main accordion card everything should be closed...

Comment: @JakobTiebel Yeah, something like that should work. I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0Lfqsb3/). Open your console, it only triggers for the one having children accordions.

Comment: @JakobTiebel Do you want to collapse children not whenever it's closed but only when it is clicked itself? Not on other elements forcing collapse?

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. See my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29qowfe1/ - Children-collapsible should not close other children-collapsible. Only Parent (main) should close all children too when closed

Comment: @JakobTiebel ok, I get it, it's because of bubbling. I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/38vLjfp1/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: great, exactly that is what I need! Thank you very much! (what is bubbling?)

Comment: @JakobTiebel the event keeps going up to the parents, and when it hit the parent accordion, triggered the event that collapses everything.